# AngularJS template inside directive. Change the Style?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The css inside the directive does not compile and leads to single color green itself. I want to have different colors for different values for the value identifier and the css color should change accordingly but it always subsides to the last color for all the thermometer widget. Please help.

```
angular.module('directives').directive('thermometer', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE'
        , replace: true
        , transclude:true
        ,scope : {
            value : "=",
            maxValue : "=" ,
            text:"@",
            percent:"="
            }
        ,template:  function(element, attrs) {
            var html = '<div style="float:left;margin-left:40px"><style> .donation-meter {margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto; width: 80px; } .donation-meter .glass { background: #e5e5e5; border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0; display: block; height: 100px; margin: 0 35px 10px; padding: 5px; position: relative; width: 20px; } .donation-meter .amount { background:{{color}}; border-radius: 100px; display: block; width: 20px; position: absolute; bottom: 5px; } .donation-meter strong { display: block; text-align: center; } .donation-meter .goal { font-size: 20px; } .donation-meter .total { font-size: 16px; position: absolute; right: 35px; } .bulb { background: #e5e5e5; border-radius: 100px; display: block; height: 50px; margin: 0 35px 10px; padding: 5px; position: relative; top: -20px; right: 15px; width: 50px; } .bulb .red-circle { background: {{color}}; border-radius: 100px; display: block; height: 50px; width: 50px; } .bulb .filler { background: {{color}}; border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0; display: block; height: 30px; width: 20px; position: relative; top: -65px; right: -15px; z-index: 30; } </style>';
            html += '<div class="donation-meter"> <b>{{text}}</b>';
            html +=   '<b class="goal">{{maxValue }}</b> <span class="glass"> <b class="total" style="bottom:{{(value/maxValue)*100}}%">{{value}}';
            html+= '</b> <span class="amount" style="height:{{(value/maxValue)*100}}%"></span> </span> <div class="bulb"> <span class="red-circle"></span> <span class="filler"> <span></span> </span> </div> </div></div>';

            return html;

        }
        ,link:function(scope){

            scope.$watch('value',function(newValue){
                console.log("--------------------------");
                console.log();
                if(newValue==75){
                    scope.color="blue";
                }
                if(newValue==76){
                    scope.color="green";
                }
            });
        }

    }
});
```

The color always subsides to whatever is the last value. Rest of the time it works fine. Please help.

Comment: There is a small hack that might work. To your html, add a hidden `div` and in it, put a new date (through `new Date()`). That would ensure that Angular doesn't use a precompiled directive.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the color on the class `.amount` put it in the style of the element that has the class `.amount`:

```
html+= '</b> <span class="amount" ng-style="{height:(value/maxValue)*100 + '%', background: color}"></span> ...
```

Comment: Actually you can see that I am using `.amount { background:{{color}}`, so the thing is that the color value is not changing.

Comment: Not exactly, you are using it inside a style tag, which might not be tracked by angular, so the color might change but the change won't cascade to the view, using it with ng-style makes sure it is managed by angular

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to put the template on an outside file, like thermometer.html, you just have to specify the location like this:

```
angular.module('directives').directive('thermometer', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE'
        , replace: true
        , transclude:true
        ,scope : {
            value : "=",
            maxValue : "=" ,
            text:"@",
            percent:"="
            }
        ; templateUrl: 'thermometer.html'
        ,link:function(scope){

            scope.$watch('value',function(newValue){
                console.log("--------------------------");
                console.log();
                if(newValue==75){
                    scope.color="blue";
                }
                if(newValue==76){
                    scope.color="green";
                }
            });
        }

    }
});
```

And then create the html file:
    < div style=...>
        ...
    < /div>

Answer (score 0):

By putting the variable inside a `<style>` rule, you're redefining the css class each time your directive gets placed on the page -- so if the first instance of the directive sets

`.donation-meter .amount { background:red}`

but  the next one sets it to

`.donation-meter .amount { background:green}`

then the last css rule is going to override the previous ones and therefore apply to all `.donation-meter .amount` elements on the page.

You should extract most of your CSS into a stylesheet rather than re-rendering it for every instance of the directive.  For the parts where you need variable style rules, use ng-class where possible:

`<div ng-class="{red: newValue < 75, green: newValue >74}">...</div>`

or else set the variable style directly on the element rather than on a class rule:

`<div style="background-color: {{color}}">`

instead of

`<style>.foo {background-color: {{color}}</style> <div class="foo"></div>`